# Java sockets server client scenario

Tags: java, ping, multicast

This is my problem statement:

A multi threaded server sends out periodic message "any clients there". Client machines need to respond with message just to prove that clients do exist on a particular IP.

Doubts:

Is this how I should proceed?

1. Client sends out a multicast message.
   2.Assuming that the client machine has no client is not listening on a particular port i.e. no program is running on the client, how do I do it?
2. If 2 is not possible, how do I know that there are clients on my network(without a program running on the client)? Please don't suggest ZeroConf as I can't get crossed over ethernet cables here.

In fact, I'm curious how a simple network discovery program can list all the other computers on the network without any program running on the client. Should I use Java Ping()?

Comment: You're trying to discover machines that expose some service usually so that service (whatever it is) can broadcast alive messages (multicast probably)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way (since Java 5) to find out if a particular client exists is to use the [`isReachable()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#isReachable%28int%29) method on InetAddress, which pretty much does everything for you (you just need to specify a timeout.) The javadoc link above gives some insight into how it works. [This](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0093.html) gives some alternatives if you're pre-Java 5 (or just want to implement your own thing.)

For multiple clients, have a look [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/datagrams/broadcasting.html) which shows how to broadcast on the server side to a particular group.

Comment: @berry120- Thanks! But how do applications like the virtual machine manager(since I'm using it) discover other machines on my LAN. Does the algo resemble: Use isReachable() and find out the IPs of all the machines(aka broadcast a datagram), hence get the alive machines and perform the operations?  Forgive my ignorance, I'm new to n/w programming.

Comment: @Kevin- My server program has to find all the physical machines on my LAN. This should be possible when I run the program on any machine, on any network. There should be no client side program.